# Program returning: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql

I looked through all the previously asked similar questions and they all have different code so can't find an answer!

My problem is that my program returns

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

when my php code is run when requesting information from mysql database. Here is my code:

```
<body>
<?php
// Connexion à la base de données
include_once("connexionMysql.php");

// test si bouton ok
if (isset($_POST['valid'])) {
    // construction de la req. 
    $requete="SELECT mdp, type FROM AY_users 
            WHERE login='.$_POST['login'].'"; 
    // exécution de la requête
    $reponse = $bdd->query($requete);

    if ($donnees=$reponse->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        if ($donnees['mdp']==$_POST['mdp']) {
            // le mot de passe est le bon

            print "<br/>Authentification réussie ! <br/>\n";
            if($donnees['type']==0){
                header("Location: pageDaccueilAdmin.php");
            }
            if($donnees['type']==1){
                header("Location: pageDaccueilEnseignant.php");
            }
            if($donnees['type']==2){
                header("Location: pageDaccueilCher.php");
            }
        } else {
            print "Le mot de passe n'est pas le bon, veuillez reessayer<br/>";
            print "<a href='authentif.php'>Se reconnecter</a>";
        }
    } else {
        // sinon : login inexistant
        print "Ce login est inexistant, veuillez <br/>\n";
        print "1- <a href='authentif.php'>Se reconnecter</a>";
        print "2- <a href='creer.php'>créer un compte</a>";
    }

}

?>
```

It definitely connects to the database as I have a print statement to make sure. (mdp-->password)*

Comment: it failed and you need to find out why http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php - http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: `$requete="SELECT mdp, type FROM AY_users WHERE login='".$_POST['login']."'";` That should fix your error, but will still leave you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Also, make use of the prepared statements to prevent SQL injection attacks. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yuo have wrong formatted quotes the your query don't get any istance from db

try this way

```
$requete="SELECT mdp, type FROM AY_users 
        WHERE login='" .$_POST['login']. "'"; 
// exécution de la requête
$reponse = $bdd->query($requete);
```

Comment: Ah okay think that got it working! Thanks

Comment: well if working please mark the answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

`PDO::query()` returns a **PDOStatement object**, or **FALSE** on failure.

Your query is failing (returning false). That's why you get the *non-object* error: `$response` is not an object. It's `bool(false)` in this case.